# Value from Previous Row with a value, some previous rows don't have a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a query that returns a row number and a "Retail" value.  My result set though sometimes doesn't contain a value for this "Retail" value.  In addition, it could be several prior rows before I have a "Retail" value for this particular item.  I'm trying to create a query which will return a "Retail" value from the 1st row (whichever row number that may be) that contains a "Retail" value.

In the below example on Row 46 I want to pull the value from Row 45.  However in Row 53 and 54 I want to pull the value from Row 52.

Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at lead and lag functions

Comment: Please post your query and script to create sample data.

Comment: Can you please also add the source data of your query, rather than its result?  This is likely easier to resolve when not working from an intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions. Unfortunately SQL Server does not support the `ignore nulls` option to `lag()` (few databases do...), but we can work around this with some gaps-and-islands technique.

The idea is to build groups of adjacent rows (islands) with a window sum that increments for each non-`null` retail value. We can then use that information to bring the "missing" values.

```
select 
    t.*,
    max(retail) over(partition by grp) real_retail
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(case when retail is null then 0 else 1 end) over(order by rn) grp
    from mytable t
) t
```